# Source install Apache 2.2.13 + PHP 5.3 + Snow Leopard

Tags: php, mysql, apache, osx-snow-leopard

Can anyone direct me to or write their experiences installing Apache and PHP on Snow Leopard?

I had this working in the past on Leopard, it would die after a security update, but was as simple as:

```
$ ./configure --enable-layout=Darwin --enable-mods-shared=all
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

and I was up and running again.

Since the Snow Leopard update I get the following issue on make command

```
libtool: link: cannot find the library `/usr/lib/libexpat.la' or unhandled argument `/usr/lib/libexpat.la'
make[2]: *** [htpasswd] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Comment: I know someone out there has an answer to this. I have gotten further in my compiling by installing missing libraries and symlinking but still getting errors.

Comment: 1K views, awesome, looks like more than just myself needs an answer to this. Would someone please step up and provide a solution? Thank you.

Comment: Really wish I could figure this one out…

Comment: UPDATE: Getting close to a solution, unfortunately iconv has serious issues during the php 5.3 make:

Undefined symbols:
  "_libiconv_open", referenced from:
      _do_convert in gdkanji.o
      _convert in encodings.o
  "_libiconv", referenced from:
      _do_convert in gdkanji.o
      _convert in encodings.o
  "_libiconv_close", referenced from:
      _do_convert in gdkanji.o
      _convert in encodings.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [libs/libphp5.bundle] Error 1

Comment: Finally 2k views later, tonnes of research, banging my head on a  desk, processes of elimination during ./configure, and no viable answers here; I have a solution and a working source install of Apache 2.2.14 + PHP 5.3 + Snow Leopard! Unfortunately I can't use XMLRPC or ICONV in my solution since there is some kind of conflict when compiling PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As most of you know Snow Leopard (SL) is based on 64-bit architecture, and when you install Xcode 3.2 that comes with SL the gcc compiler defaults to 4.2.1 and seems to default to x86_64 not i386.

Thanks to the following websites:

- http://hivelogic.com/articles/compiling-mysql-on-snow-leopard/
- http://projects.serenity.de/php/
- http://dawsdesign.com/drupal/comment/reply/30#comment-form
- http://pixelchimp.net/blog/pixel-chimp/reverting-php-53-5210-snow-leopard(most helpful for finding the other sites)
- http://www.kevinkorb.com/post/24
- http://www.latko.org/2009/01/31/compiling-64-bit-apachephp-on-mac-os-x-1056/
- http://www.gen-x-design.com/archives/recompiling-php-5-3-on-snow-leopard-with-freetype-support/

My Solution:

1. Follow the instructions on hivelogic.com for installing MySQL on SL
2. Install Apache 2.2.14 via instructions on http://projects.serenity.de/php/ - it uses 2.2.13 but replacing a 13 with a 14 is easy right? ;) After Apache (x86_64) is installed do the following:

   > ```
   > cd /usr/local/apache2/bin
   > cp httpd /usr/sbin/
   > cp apachectl /usr/sbin/
   > ```
   >
   > As mentioned on http://www.kevinkorb.com/post/24
3. Compile and install packages (freetype,gettext,libjpeg,libpng,mcrypt,mhash,etc) mentioned right after the Apache install instructions on http://projects.serenity.de/php/ until IMAP, if you need IMAP then try the instructions mentioned in the url above but I didn't install since I didn't need it.

   > **NOTE**: These all compiled as x86_64 with the exception of **libpng** which required the the following to be compiled as 64-bit:
   >
   > *export CFLAGS="-arch x86_64" ./configure
4. This is where all the head banging on a desk and trial and error occurred. The installation of PHP 5.3.0. The biggest issue is with ICONV which has linking issues. I searched all over Google and some others were successful by editing the iconv.c file and the Makefile by adding -lresolv to the EXTRA_LIBS= after the ./configure string was executed. I was not so lucky, but still needed to make the edits for the *--without-iconv* parameter to work. Also *--with-xmlrpc* would not work. For the iconv hacks please refer to this [blog entry](http://www.gen-x-design.com/archives/recompiling-php-5-3-on-snow-leopard-with-freetype-support/)

So here is my ./configure string:

```
./configure 
--prefix=/usr/local/php5
--without-iconv
--with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs
--enable-pdo
--with-gd 
--with-zlib 
--with-jpeg-dir=/usr/local 
--with-png-dir=/usr/local 
--with-libxml-dir=/usr/local 
--with-curl 
--with-mcrypt 
--with-pdo-mysql=/usr/local/mysql 
--with-mysqli=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config 
--with-mysql=/usr/local/mysql 
--with-mhash 
--with-libxml-dir=/usr/local 
--with-t1lib=/usr/local 
--with-xsl 
--with-freetype-dir=/usr/local 
--with-gettext 
--with-bz2=/usr 
--with-openssl=/usr 
--enable-bcmath 
--enable-calendar 
--enable-cgi 
--enable-exif 
--enable-ftp 
--enable-gd-native-ttf 
--enable-mbstring 
--enable-soap 
--enable-sqlite-utf8 
--enable-cli 
--enable-wddx 
--enable-zip

make
sudo make install
```

---

On a final note, I downloaded PHP-5.3.2-dev (http://snaps.php.net/) and it seems to have fixed the linking issues with ICONV and XMLRPC. The only changes that I've made to the above ./configure string were replace *--without-iconv* with *--with-iconv=/usr/local* and added *--with-xmlrpc*. This is a dev version and I am sure that it still has bugs so use at your own discretion.

If you are having any issues please feel free to comment and I will try to help!

Comment: hey, i know this is old but the link you have for installing apache2 no longer has instructions on that... can you update your answer by any chance to include how to install apache2?

Answer (score 2):

See here:
http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49267

Basically:

1. Add "-lresolv" to MH_BUNDLE_FLAGS, EXTRA_LDFLAGS and
   EXTRA_LDFLAGS_PROGRAM in "Makefile"
2. Change "ext/iconv/iconv.c"

   #define iconv libiconv

   to:

   #define iconv iconv

As they say, worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

In apache source directory

```
cd srclib/apr-util/xml/expat
./configure
# OR ./configure --prefix=/{{YOURDIR}}/apache/source/httpd-2.2.22/srclib/apr-util/xml/expat/
sudo make install
# OR make install
```

Remember to clean up your previous apache install after make install failed

```
cd {{YOURDIR}}/apache/
ls -la
rm -r bin
rm -r build
rm -r include
rm -r lib
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you have no need for a custom built version of PHP than perhaps the one Apple provides will do, but that is not the case, with the person who asked the question, or me for that matter as I seek an answer to the same question. Does anyone else have a suggestion?

Comment: Hi Alan, did you find any solutions to this yet?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you didnt install the developer tools!

Answer (score 0):

The guys from Liip maintain a great package for PHP and Apache on OS X, with really easy install. The package is very suitable for development. You could check it out here: http://php-osx.liip.ch/

> This package installs the (usually) latest PHP 5.3.x/5.4.x on OS X 10.6 (aka Snow Leopard) and OS X 10.7 (aka Lion) in /usr/local/php5. It installs many useful extensions (see below) and ini-settings and is what we at Liip and Local.ch use for our development. It's especially suited for Symfony 2 development. It also provides a decent php.ini with all settings configured according to "Best Practices".

You can then use the standard Apache and install MySQL (x64) with the package from the MySQL website.

Answer (score -2):

Mac OS X Snow Leopard already comes with Apache 2.2 and PHP 5.3 pre-installed. Please see:

http://www.brandonsavage.net/first-glance-apples-snow-leopard/

It is probably best to leave those alone, as they are optimally configured for Snow Leopard.

Comment: Thank you Michael, I am aware that these are installed by default, I prefer the compile from source method.